# Exporting arrow function unexpected token

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to combine laravel with https://github.com/vue-bulma/vue-admin. Unfortunately, npm build always throws Unexpected token. I am using laravel-mix.

[image]

Any ideas what could be invalid with this export? I am asking this question because I want to find out if this is invalid syntax, that way I can tell if I am supposed to look somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import` is a statement.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

so while this works:

```
var import_ = function(x){ return x; };
var x = (a) => () => import_(a + 1);
x(3)()
/*
4
*/
```

this fails syntactically (tested in FF scratchpad (Shift-F4))

```
var x = (a) => () => import("");
x(3)()
/*
Exception: SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'import'
@Scratchpad/1:2
*/
```

while on node you get a different error message, but essentially the same

```
$ node
> var x = (a) => () => import("");
var x = (a) => () => import("");
                     ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Comment: This is understandable. What I am wondering now is how come it works when not in laravel mix environment https://github.com/vue-bulma/vue-admin/blob/master/client/store/modules/menu/lazyLoading.js

Comment: @Pernick, probably due to *"Note: if you are using Babel, you will need to add the [syntax-dynamic-import](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/) plugin so that Babel can properly parse the syntax."* seen at [doc](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html)